# Showing that a certain map is not flat by explicit counterexample

Tags: commutative-algebra, flatness

> I wish to show that the injection $k[y^2, y^3] \rightarrow k[y]$ is not flat.

I know of geometric ways to see this, but I wish to see explicitly $k[y^2, y^3]$-modules (or localizations thereof) $0 \rightarrow M' \rightarrow M$ which does not remain injective upon tensoring with $k[y]$. Is such a search futile?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "geometric proof" automatically produces an algebraic proof. The singularity on the cusp corresponds to the maximal ideal $(y^2,y^3)  \subseteq k[y^2,y^3]$.

The inclusion $(y^2,y^3) \subseteq k[y^2,y^3]$ doesn't stay injective when tensored with $k[y^2,y^3] \to k[y]$. In fact, $y^2 \otimes y$ and $y^3 \otimes 1$ have the same image under $(y^2,y^3) \otimes_{k[y^2,y^3]} k[y] \to k[y]$, but are not equal.

Comment: Hi @Martin could you elaborate further? What is the injection of $k[y^2, y^3]$-modules that you are hinting it?

Comment: I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Could you give a hint for $y^2 \otimes y\ne y^3 \otimes 1$?

Comment: Mod out $(y^2,y^3)^2$.

Comment: This works. Thanks!

Comment: What have to mod out by the square of maximal ideal and how? Are you suggesting somehow to tensor $(y^2,y^3) \otimes_{k[y^2,y^3]} k[y]$ by $k$?

Comment: Yes. This will give you the map on cotangent spaces, which is $k^2 \to k$.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Sorry to rekindle this question after many years... But I'm really not clear how to mod out $(y^2, y^3)^2$. Could you explain this? This is also stated in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669818/direct-proof-of-non-flatness but I don't see why it holds... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to add a short algebraic proof (although this is not exactly what you asked for) which shows [again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/385364/integral-closure-tildea-is-flat-over-a-then-a-is-integrally-closed) the usefulness of Exercise 7.2 in Matsumura, *Commutative Ring Theory*:

> If $A\subset B$ are integral domains with the same field of fractions and $B$ is faithfully flat over $A$, then $A=B$.

In your case $A=k[y^2,y^3]$ and $B=k[y]$. If the extension is flat, then it is faithfully flat (since it is integral) and therefore $A=B$, a contradiction.