# Intersection of submodules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

I have question regarding intersection of submodules.

> Could anyone give example of a commutative ring $R$ with identity and an $R$-module $M$ such that $$IM\cap JM\nsubseteq (I\cap J)M$$ for some ideals $I$ and $J$ of $R$?

Thank you.

Comment: Related (see answer below): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587838

Answer (score 4):

The equality is ensured by the flatness of $M$. This leads us to consider "classical" examples of non-flat modules such as: $R=k[x^2,x^3]$, $M=k[x]$, $I=x^2R$ and $J=x^3R$.